# Proof-verification: $\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,bc)=1\iff(\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,b)=1)\land(\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,c)=1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before, but I'd like to get my proof verified nevertheless.

> **Proposition:**  $\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,bc)=1\iff(\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,b)=1)\land(\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,c)=1)$

> **Proof 1(Plain English):**  $\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,b)=1$ means that $a$ and $b$ are coprimes, and hence do not have any common prime factors. Similarly, $a$ and $c$ do not have any common prime factors. Since by multiplying $b$ and $c$ no new prime factors are introduced, thus $a$ must be coprime to $b\cdot c$ as well, which means $\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,bc)=1$. Converse: $\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,bc)=1$ means that $a$ does not have any common prime factors with either $b$ or $c$, for if it did, the $\mathrm{g.c.d}$ would not be $1$. This implies $a$ is coprime to both $b$ and $c$, and hence $\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,b)=1$ and $\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,c)=1$. **This completes the proof.**

> **Proof 2:** $$\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,bc)=1\iff\forall d>1((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid bc))$$ $$\iff\forall d>1((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid b)\land(d\nmid c))$$ $$\iff\forall d>1((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid b)\land(d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid c))$$ $$\iff\forall d>1((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid b))\land\forall d>1((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid c))$$ $$\iff(\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,b)=1)\land(\mathrm{g.c.d}(a,c)=1)$$which completes the proof.

**I'd like to know about any errors/obstacles in my approaches.** Also, which of these two approaches is generally preferable?

Comment: Both are correct. And obviously the second one's more preferable; the first one sounds like the language used in olympiads. While you need not use so many quantifiers, yet it is fine.

Comment: @Shamim I see; this question appears in Ch.0 of Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, and Gallian often uses a mixed language, consisting of some English and some symbols. How can I cut down on the quantifiers, though?

Comment: I haven't seen that book yet. Well for handling quantifiers, you can just write 'and' instead of always using '$\wedge$' .

Comment: @Shamim Oh, so I can make it more readable by removing some symbols. Point noted. :)

Comment: It looks comfortable :)

Comment: I have only a minor remark about the second iff in the second proof, that is, $\forall d>1((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid b)\land(d\nmid c)) \iff\forall d>1((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid b)\land(d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid c))$. This is absolutely true, but if you fix a specific $d > 1$, then it is not true that $((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid b)\land(d\nmid c)) \iff((d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid b)\land(d\nmid a)\land(d\nmid c))$. A grader might mark you down for this. But quantify over *primes* $d$ and you take no risk.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you for the input. For convenience, while writing I chose to write $d>1$ rather than $d\in\Bbb P$, but I'll make sure to prefer the latter from now on. The precision in mathematical statements never fails to amaze me!

Comment: My comment was more about the *people* doing Maths, though. As I said, a finnicky grader may think "Is this guy aware that the iff does not hold true for each individual $d$?" So, my advice would be not not to take this risk.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti With all honesty, *I wasn't aware* until you pointed it out. I assumed $d>1$ and $d\in\Bbb P$ would produce identical results. Being finicky is a positive attribute for mathematicians, it seems. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no errors in either of your proofs.

The second one is more preferable since it is in language more suited to mathematical answers than the first.

However, the first suits an answer "in conversation", i.e. if you were telling your friend the answer to the question, I guess it makes more sense to say the first proof , than to go "for all $d$, ..."

In short, you would be advised to not write an answer of the first kind in an exam , if you want marks, and you would not be advised to speak the second answer to a person in conversation, if you want more clarity.